# How to interpret the code "x=numeric(n)"?

Tags: r, simulation, markov-chains

I have codes in R, simulate Markov Chain

```
P = matrix(c(0,1,0,.2,0,.8,.1,.3,.6),nrow=3,byrow=T)
n = 10000
x = numeric(n)
pi0 = c(.5, 0, .5)
state = sample(1:3, 1, prob=pi0)
x[1] = state
for(i in 2:n){
  state = sample(1:3, 1, prob = P[state,])
  x[i] = stat
}
```

x = numeric(n) looks like gives me 10000 zero number. What's the goal for numeric(n)? Why do I need many 0's?

Help file said "numeric is identical to double (and real). It creates a double-precision vector of the specified length with each element equal to 0." Maybe due to my English, I don't understand what does that mean.

Comment: It's a way to allocate a vector. It would be equivalent to `rep(0, n)` or `c(0, 0, 0, ...)` repeating n times.

Comment: hi, it appears to create a vector of the given length, with each element initially 0. so it's a vector with 10,000 elements, all 0.

Comment: One of the main motivations for this is that it is more efficient than starting with a small vector and then incrementally making it larger in a loop. The 0's in the vector aren't really important here. The point is that the space to hold 10000 numbers has been pre-allocated with the 0's functioning as place holders.

Comment: @JohnColeman So what the advantages of this code compared than, say, rep(0,10000)?

Comment: @ChiaoChao No advantage that I can see. R often gives you multiple ways of doing essentially the same thing. `rep` is capable of doing so much more than allocating a vector, but when used in this way there is no difference.